# Android : How to calculate aspect ratio of images?

Tags: android

I have 100 images of huge size (500*700 , 401*800 , 2345* 3567) , so I want all these images height same as 220. Below I'm implementing calculation for the aspect ratio of image. I want to set the fixed height of all huge size images. I'm using some arithmetic formula to calculate the aspect ratio but getting all images width as same, and height is different but I want height to be fixed. How to get the fixed height? Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my calculation code for image aspect ratio

```
if (bitmapResizeImage != null) {
    int originalWidth = bitmapResizeImage.getWidth();
    int originalHeight = bitmapResizeImage.getHeight();
    Log.e("originalWidth "," = " + originalWidth +" originalHeight = " + originalHeight+" of imgElement = " + imgElement+ " Notation = " +all_Post.getStrNotationNo());

    float aspect_ratio = originalWidth / originalHeight ;
    Log.e("aspect_ratio "," = " + aspect_ratio);

    float adjusted_width = 220 * originalWidth / originalHeight ;
    Log.e("adjusted_width "," = " + adjusted_width);
    float adjusted_height = originalWidth * originalHeight / originalWidth ;
    Log.e("adjusted_height "," = " + adjusted_height);

    pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapResizeImage);
}
```

Comment: and what do you see in the logcat  about `aspect_ratio`?

Comment: This formula can be simplified with some basic math: `originalWidth * originalHeight / originalWidth`

Comment: so correct it to be a right value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably try `typecasting`:

```
float aspect_ratio = (float)originalWidth / (float)originalHeight ;
```

Because this typecasting operation will return a float value.

Integer divided by Integer will give the result as integer, which will be assigned to a float variable. Hence the operands need to be converted to float, in order to make sure that the result is computed as float.

Comment: I have change using your code line . But even not getting proper width and height. means height wise width.

Comment: float aspect_ratio = (float)originalWidth / (float)originalHeight ;float newImageWidth = aspect_ratio * (float)originalWidth ; Is this right ?

Comment: Yes it is right. Check if you're getting correct values in originalWidth and originalHeight

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Priyank has posted, once you have the correct values
you can create a bitmap with the new dimensions before using setImageBitmap on the ImageView. Use

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config));
```